# what i should put as job title

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to find the proper job title since I am working as:
 - programmer
 - database administrator
 - backup operator
 - IT

and I do work alone as IT, among 20 employees in accounting and administration departments.

Comment: Maybe "IT Support (Engineer)", very broad term, but as you work on your own then possible you do all the IT related stuff so it might fit better.

Comment: *IT* isn't a job description, it's a field of work. You can work *in* IT, but you can't work *as* an IT. The most likely general term for everything you describe is *systems administrator*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this type of question is better for workplace SE or a job  board, and isn't about EL&U per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason Bassford said, *"Systems Administrator"* or *"System Administrator"* is probably what you are looking for. However this is a very very broad and variable term.